# How get numbers from given range with given condition in R

Tags: r

I want to get all numbers that are greater than 0 and lesser than 1e6 and does not contain digit 4. How is that possible, please?

My try was:

```
library(prob)
A <- c(0:(1e6-1))
V <- subset(A, /*I don't know what to put here*/)
```

But I don't know how to state that I want all numbers that does not contain digit 4....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `grep` to find out indices with numbers containing `4` and remove them with negative subsetting.

```
A = 0:1e6
V = A[-grep(4,A)]
```